# Apply multiple CSS rules with one selector

Tags: html, css

If for example, I have a lot of CSS styles that only have to apply to objects within a div `#container`. Is it possible to instead of write #container in front of all, have another type of selector? So I don't have to write it for EVERY object within the div `#container`?

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="letter">a</div>
    <div class="letter">b</div>
    <div class="number">1</div>
    <div class="number">2</div>
</div>
<div class="letter">c</div>
<div class="number">3</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.letter {
    font-size:25px;
    color:green;
}
.number {
    font-size:30px;
    color:red;
}
```

I want to write a rule for every `.letter` and `.number` within `#container`.

Ofcourse I'm only reproducing my issue here, but is there a possibility to change the rules of `.letter` and `.number` so it applies only to `#container` without having to change it 2 times (2 times in this reproduction)? (In my issue it's about 30 objects).

---

I tried a `#container` selector before those rules, but without succes. It breaks the styles.

**My CSS attempt:**

```
#container {
    .letter {
        font-size:25px;
        color:green;
    }
    .number {
        font-size:30px;
        color:red;
    }
}
```

Does anyone know a solution or do I have to manually apply `#container` in front of every rule like this *(which I want to avoid cause it's a lot of work!)*:

```
#container .letter {
    font-size:25px;
    color:green;
}

#container .number {
    font-size:30px;
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: You need to give a look at less and sass, it is going to blow your mind ;)

Comment: is pure css (as in non [less](http://lesscss.org/) or [sass](http://sass-lang.com)) a requirement ?

Comment: @birdspider I guess it is, because the developers at my company don't use this extension at all.

Comment: @DaanHeskes, if you the only one writing the css, less (and I assume sass) compiles down to css - so if you are solely responsible for said css you want at least try one of those. As to your question I am not aware of any CSS mechanism for that, but maybe some CSS3 gurus might have a trick up their sleeves.

Comment: Am I the only one getting a little confused by reading this? _(which I want to avoid cause it's a lot of work!)_, what's a lot of work about copying and pasting #container 30x, this post surely took more time to write + make up an example than this would have done (in my eyes anyway ^^).

Comment: @Callum. I'm going to create a test-page which has a dynamic class on the body object. If wouldn't want to write this in front of every rule to then change it all back again to the other page's dynamic class if it could be done with some other simple way. I started wondering and wrote this question to improve my knowledge, not to actually save time. I just want to get as efficient as possible in the future. :) Also, I'm not writing this in worktime but in my spare time.

Comment: @Daan That makes more sense now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YES, CSS is quite stupid and simple, you have no other choose than having #container in front of each class.

### BUT

Developers are lazy and created a pre-processing language to add some crazy functionality. Currently, two alternatives : [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) and [LESS](http://lesscss.org)

But using those technology you can write your styles like this :

```
nav {
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
  }

  li { display: inline-block; }

  a {
    display: block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

and then automatically generate a CSS file like that :

```
nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

nav a {
  display: block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

This is called **"Nesting"** and is only one of the many stuff you will love.

### Which one to use between SASS and LESS ?

They are similar, my recommandation is us an existing framework and look which one is available. For exemple bootstrap use LESS and Foundation use SASS ... but both are quite similar.

I use both daily, and have some preference to SASS, but that my own opinion.

Comment: So if I simply copy and paste my CSS into either of those CSS extensions, and write the code as I tried which failed. It'll then generate the code I want so I can stay lazy?

Comment: Mmh ... the best would be to use a task manager like Grunt or Gulp ... first give a quite look at how to use those tools, then may be give a look at Grunt but it is very common to have a grunt task looking at all your .scss or .less files and automatically generating a compile/minimized CSS at each save.

Comment: You should start step by step, first use less / SASS to be familiar with, don't rush to fast on task managing if you are not really familiar with them.

Comment: Thanks for all the information, I've heard about these extensions but never really wanted to get into them because for me it wasn't clear what it did. Now it's definitely something I'm going to get into.

Comment: Be prepare to save a lot of time, and never being able to go back ;), which is kinda why we hangout on stack overflow, change people's life with such awesome solution. Have fun :D

Comment: I also use a plugin named **Zen Coding** which also makes this possible, but I wanted to know if there was a pure CSS way. Have you heard of this plugin and do you think SASS saves more time or is more useful in any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I also use ZenCoding in my text editor (sublimeText) but mostly for HTML ... SASS will also let you use variable, calculation ... and yes it is a real time saver but you might need to spend some times integrating it well in your project. So both are compatible, and work well together ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will really get into this and I can't thank you enough for helping. Ofcourse my appreciation goes to everyone answering this question, but you seemed so much more willing to help. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

In pure CSS, I can't think of a better way of doing it than what you're already doing - which is a lot of repetitive work as you've pointed out.

Your first "CSS attempt" is the correct approach, but you will have to use [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) or [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) if you want to be able to nest selectors like that. Pure CSS doesn't support it.

I strongly recommand that you look into SASS/LESS, they offer much more than just nested selectors and they will make your CSS coding a lot more enjoyable overall.

Answer (score 1):

CSS is, by design, a very simple language. There is no way (yet) to achieve what you want with pure CSS.

[CSS preprocessors](https://github.com/showcases/css-preprocessors) such as LESS and SASS have stepped in to help alleviate the tedium of this and other common problems with traditional CSS (such as variables). Your nested example is exactly right in SASS. These all compile to plain old CSS, but will necessitate a change to your front-end build process.

If you can't make use of a preprocessor, find + replace is your friend.

Answer (score 1):

**The answer is No.**

You can't do that without using a preprocessor like less or sass.

Take a look at SASS for example http://sass-lang.com/guide in the "Nesting" section you can see that's exactly the feature your're looking for.

If you want to try it follow the [instructions](http://sass-lang.com/install) should be pretty simple.

The same feature is present in the [less](http://lesscss.org/) preprocessor but my opinion is that SASS is much more powerful and flexible so if you have to start from sketch go for this one.

If you can't go for a preprocessor then preceding every selector with `#container` is the only way you have.